# Schuld oder Scham

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberlebenden-Syndrom) spricht davon, dass Überlebende von Flugzeugabstürzen sich gelegentlich für ihr Weiterleben schuldig fühlen, obwohl sie objektiv keine Schuld am Flugzeugabsturz tragen. Weder haben sie diesen kommen sehen, noch hätten sie ihn verhindern können, schon gar nicht haben sie zum Absturz beigetragen.

Derartigen Gebrauch des Wortes "Schuld" habe ich schon oft im Zusammenhang mit Überleben gehört, aber er scheint mir falsch, und ich frage mich, ob hier vielleicht Scham mit Schuld verwechselt wird, weil Scham oft mit Schuld einhergeht.

Nachdem meine vorherige Frage von manchen nicht verstanden wurde wie sie gemeint war: Mir ist der Begriff Überlebenden-Syndrom durchaus geläufig. Es geht nicht darum die Anwesenheit dieser Gefühle in Zweifel zu ziehen - es geht darum zu fragen ob der Begriff glücklich gewählt ist. Es sollte auch keine Rolle spielen wer den Begriff verwendet - der Überlebende selbst, ein Psychologe oder sonstwer.

Ich halte es für Allgemeingut, dass man Schuld nur erwirbt, wenn man einerseits intentional handelt, also weiß, dass das eigene Handeln bestimmte Folgen zeitigen wird, andererseits das eigene Handeln kausal ist für eine Folge, und drittens man eine Handlungsalternative hat. Deswegen halte ich den Begriff für schlecht.

Wie begründet man die Begriffswahl, wenn man an dem Begriff festhalten will? Gäbe einen anderen, besseren Begriff - nicht unbedingt aber vielleicht *Scham*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es ist richtig, dass oft von „Schuld“ in Kontexten gesprochen wird, in denen der „Schuldige“ nicht durch eigenes Zutun in diese Lage geraten ist, also semantisch wohl das Wort „Scham“ näher liegen würde.
Ich stimme dem Fragensteller zu und verweise darauf, dass die deutsche Sprache diese Verwendung des Begriffes „Scham“ auch kennt. Als ein Beispiel könnte ich den Zweiten Weltkrieg anführen. Japanische Soldaten fühlten oft eine Art „Scham“, wenn sie ein Gefecht oder dergleichen überlebten, der Sieg aber vom Gegner davon getragen wurde. Warum ich dieses Beispiel heranziehe? Es ist eines der wenigen, in denen man auch in der deutschen Sprache das Wort „Scham“ vorzieht. Es wird darauf verwiesen, diese Soldaten würden aus einem falschen oder überzogenen Ehrgefühl heraus eine Scham empfinden. Hier wird eindeutig der Begriff „Schuld“ vermieden. Ich vermute, das hängt damit zusammen, dass der Sprecher mit der Begriffswahl – indirekt und nur sachte – eine inhaltliche Distanz zu der Sichtweise des jeweiligen Soldaten ausdrücken möchte.

Meines Erachtens hat der Verfasser der Frage auch noch außer Acht gelassen, dass die beiden von ihm gegenübergestellten Begriffe eine verschiedene Intensität beinhalten. Scham wiegt in den meisten Kontexten geringer als Schuld. Schuld ist ein bedeutend härteres Wort, das nicht umsonst Assoziationen mit der Justiz hervorruft. Um die Bedeutung des Intensitätsunterschiedes klarzumachen, salopp gesagt: Für seine Schuld kann der Richter jemanden verurteilen, für seine Scham nicht.

Hilft das vielleicht ein wenig weiter?

Comment: Teils. Den Absatz zu den Soldaten finde ich interessant. Unten das, zur angeblichen Härte der Begriffe, nicht. Schuld und Scham sind qualitativ unterschieden, nicht quantitativ. Wie misst man die Härte eines Wortes? Gar nicht, weil es nicht geht. Vor Gericht kann man sich alle möglichen Empfindungen denken, die alle nicht verurteilt werden. Unabhängig vom Gefühl verurteilt ein Richter ja auch faktische Schuld, nicht Schuldgefühle. Im Gegenteil können diese als Reue schuldmindernd wirken. Mit Attributen 'heftige Schamgefühle', 'vage Schuldgefühle' kann man Intensitäten ausdrücken.

Answer (score 7):

M.E. kann nicht einfach aufgrund logischer Überlegung der Begriff "Schuld" als missglückt oder deplaziert abgetan werden. Die betroffenen Überlebenden fühlen sich tatsächlich schuldig; subjektiv glauben sie, dass sie für die Opfer mehr hätten tun können und sollen, selbst wenn sie objektiv gar nichts tun konnten und keinerlei Verantwortung am Ereignis trugen. Das ist halt die Sache mit psychischen Leiden, da spielen objektive Überlegungen nun mal keine große Rolle. "Scham" wäre vielleicht der richtige Begriff aus Betrachtersicht, aber innerlich fühlen sich die Betroffenen wohl tatsächlich schuldig, mit allem was das impliziert.

Comment: Jetzt mit größerem Abstand frage ich mich, was "innerlich fühlen" sein soll. Ist Fühlen nicht immer innerlich? Und damit zu tun hat auch die Frage, dass die Überlebenden glauben mehr hätten tun können. Solche Gedanken kommen meines Erachtens nach den Gefühlen und sind Rationalisierungen, aber das Gefühl selbst ist vor den Gedanken da. Aus Mangel an Erfahrung mit starken Gefühlen büchst die Vernunft dann gerne aus und stammelt sich was zurecht.